# CSS To Extend Navigation To Content Length

Tags: html, css, navigation

I've tried a lot of suggestions from Stack Overflow on how to get my navigation to extend to the bottom of my content. None of the suggestions seem to work for me.

Right now, I'm setting `html` and `body` to `height: 100%;` and that isn't working.

Can someone provide some advice?

http://jsfiddle.net/8XsAY/

Basically, I just want the left and right nav bars to extend to the size of the content div.
`div#leftNav.height = div#content.height`

I know it is possible with JavaScript but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Thank you everyone for your responses. I have been unable to get any to work, most likely due to my own inability to style using CSS. Therefore, I have used JavaScript to fix the issue.

Using JQuery:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    navHeightAdjust();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    navHeightAdjust();
});

function navHeightAdjust() {
    var contentHeight = $("div#content").height();
    var leftNavHeight = $("div#leftNav").height();
    var rightNavHeight = $("div#rightNav").height();

    var newHeight = Math.max(contentHeight, leftNavHeight, rightNavHeight);

    $("div.nav").height(newHeight);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting #content height 100% sidenote: that your footer is at the end clearing float hence your right and left nav wont touch to page bottom. In case you need to debug you may also put border:1px solid red on #content to check

Hope it helps!

Comment: Simply adding `height: 100%;` to #content hasn't worked. I tried it just now in the fiddle and it didn't change anything, except the footer overlaps the text. I'm not too concerned about the footer; I can fix that later.

Comment: hmm you may like to check http://somacss.com/fullheight.html this in this page find for section "Here are 5 different ways"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure weather you were avoiding hard-coding your height but if you change height:100% to height:1650px it will work.

```
div.nav {
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    background-color: #B2A58A;
    width: 10%;
    padding: 0.5%;
    height: 1650px;
}
```

I also added background-color:black only for demonstration purposes. You can delete this whenever.

```
div#footer {
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    color: #B2A48A;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color:black /* to test */
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to avoid hardcoding the height. I want it to scale to content length. I can easily get it to work by hardcoding, but I would prefer scalability. Not to mention, if you resize the page, you'll see that eventually the text will overflow the 1650px as well.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: NEW**
You can now use [Grid Layout](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) to have equal height for all the adjacent column. You can use something like `display:grid; grid-auto-rows: 1fr;` in container CSS. All the child divs will match the height of the tallest sibling div.
Please refer this example to understand better --> https://codepen.io/Hlsg/pen/EXKJba

**--OLD--**
Add `overflow:hidden` inside `div#main`
and add

```
margin-bottom: -1000px;
padding-bottom: 1000px;
```

inside `div.nav` it will work like magic

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8XsAY/14/)

Comment: This doesn't appear to work for me. Chrome 32 and IE 9 both. Does it work on your JSFiddle?

Comment: Ahh seems like this is not a browser independent solution .. can also be the structure problem i will design new and check .